# Is it possible to change default ComputeModel for create database with Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database

I tried to create a database in Azure Sqlserver. "CREATE DATABASE" SQL command works. But it use default "General Purpose" as ComputeModel. Is it possible to use other option as default one.

I found the power shell command: New-AzSqlDatabase which I could use to create database with give ComputeModel. But I do not want to that way.

My target is: System admin define the default template such as ResourceGroupName, ComputeModel, MinVcore, MaxVcore etc... And developer or DBA could run SQL Command to create database without touching Azure setting at all.

Is there anyone could give me some suggstion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Gen 5 hardware in place, we are making a change to the default database configuration and the default elastic pool configuration for all new Azure SQL databases. Starting May 31, 2019, the default configuration will be a General Purpose 2 vCore database or elastic pool provisioned on Gen 5 hardware.

In SSMS, you can edit the script to create new database with the price tier which you specified.

Fore details, please reference this tutorial: [Script objects in SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/scripting-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#script-databases)

This tutorial teaches you to generate Transact-SQL (T-SQL) scripts for various objects found within SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). In this tutorial, you find examples of how to script the following objects:

- Queries, when you perform actions within the GUI
- Databases in two different ways (Script As and Generate Script)
- Tables
- Stored procedures
- Extended events

To script any object in Object Explorer, right-click it and select the Script Object As option. This tutorial shows you the process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leon, thanks for your information. But ResourceGroupName, ComputeModel, MinVcore and MaxVcore  are for Azure SQLServer only. I could not find these fields in normal Create database script.

Comment: what's your purpose? Create database doesn't need ResourceGroupName. I think you need look at he [Create database statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#azure-sql-database-single-databaseelastic-pool).  They are all contained in it.